# multiple frame animation loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, coffeescript

I'm trying to have the following scenario working.
On a page, i have 3 different banner containers. they all contains a wrapper (".copy") with at the moment 3 paragraphs (.frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3).

```
<div class="ad-wrap ad-top">
    <div class="copy">
      <p class="frame-1">frame1 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-2">frame 2 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-3">frame 3 copy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ad-wrap main-ad">
    <div class="copy">
      <p class="frame-1">frame1 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-2">frame 2 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-3">frame 3 copy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ad-wrap ad-side">
    <div class="copy">
      <p class="frame-1">frame1 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-2">frame 2 copy</p>
      <p class="frame-3">frame 3 copy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to animate them with jQuery. I can manage with one ad only but I get confused when the 3 differents ads are present on the page.
With one only, the animation works fine and loops well. with 3 ads, it's just a mess, frames appears together or dont show at all :(

This is the script that I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loader_anim;

  $('.ad').each(function() {
      $(this).load('ads-source/index.html .ad-wrap', function() {
      var $anims, $frames, i, loopAnim;
      $anims = $('.ad .copy');
      $frames = $anims.children();
      $('.loader').delay(200).fadeOut();
      i = 0;
      loopAnim = function() {
        var frame;
        if (i <= $frames.length - 1) {
          frame = $frames[i];
          return $(frame).fadeIn('slow').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            i++;
            return loopAnim();
          });
        } else {
          i = 0;
          return loopAnim();
        }
      };
      return loopAnim();
    });
  });
});
```

I know that at the moment my script rely on the fact that all ads have the same number of frames and i will have to adapt it later on to adapt to different scenarios. But at the moment i can't sort out how to make it work simultaneously on all frames.

I guess there is something obvious I don't grasp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use coffee, but best I can tell the solution is to `.each()` on the $(".ad") selector. Right now, your `$anims.children()` is applied to just the first `.ad`'s `.copy`s (or all `.copy`s on the page)

Hopefully this works / is helpful:

```
$(document).ready ->     
  #load ads
  $('.ad').each( function(){
      $(this).load('ads-source/index.html .ad-wrap', ->
        $anims = $(this).find('.copy');
        $frames = $anims.children()

        #frames anim engine
        i = 0
        loopAnim = ->
          if i <= $frames.length - 1
            frame = $frames[i]
            $(frame).fadeIn('slow').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow', ->
              i++
              loopAnim()
            )
          else
            i = 0
            loopAnim()
        loopAnim() 
      )

  });
```

Comment: nope it doesn't make a difference. the animation kind of work all of the ads, but it becomes chaotic when i have more than one in the file. I've changed the script following your suggestion.